# Batch rename files to change digit

Tags: bash

I have a directory containing multiple files.  Each file can have a different prefix and suffix, but all contain a six digit number.  I want to batch rename the files such that one of digits is changed (specifically the second).

So, for example

```
*?2????* -> *?5????*
```

The second digit is always the same for all the files, but everything else can be different.  To further complicate matters some files have two six digit numbers.  In case both numbers need to be updated,

e.g.

```
*?2????*?2????* -> *?5????*?5????*
```

Any pointers?

Comment: There are countless other questions discussing the `rename` command, and the requirements here seem far too specific to allow any generally applicable answer more specific than "loop over the files and rename the ones with matching filenames".

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for file in *?2????*; do
    if [[ $file =~ [0-9]{6} ]]; then
        echo mv "$file" "$(sed 's/2/5/g' <<< "$file")"
    else
        echo mv "$file" "$(sed 's/[0-9]/5/2' <<< "$file")"
    fi
done
```

The `sed` command will replace the 2nd occurrence of digits by 5.

If this fits your needs, simply removes the `echo` commands from my snippet.

Comment: I think the OP said that, in the case of two 6 digit strings, both strings need updating (and according to his example, in different ways).

Comment: Sorry typo.  Yes both strings need updating, but in the same way - the second digit in both strings will initially be the same and needs changing to the same digit.

Comment: Doesn't quite work as I would like.  I want to change the second digit.  Whereas your script changes all instances of 2 with 5.  But I think you've given me enough to go with and try and work it out.  Thanks.

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. If you think that the answer is well answered, you can 'accept' it by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)